# How to integrate WordPress template with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, wordpress-theming

How can CodeIgniter and WordPress be integrated such that the look and feel/template of
the WordPress blog is carried over to the CodeIgniter-created pages?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First step is to move CodeIgniter and the WordPress files in their own directory.

After that, put the following line at the top of your CodeIgniter's `index.php` file. Change the path to `wp-blog-header.php` as needed to point to your WordPress's root directory.

```
<?php
    require('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Then, you can use the following functions inside your views:

```
<?php
    get_header();
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer();    
?>
```

Other helper functions can also be found in WordPress's documentation which can
assist you in integrating the design.

Answer (score 16):

When I included the file wp-blog-header.php in Codeigniter's index.php page, I got a problem that site_url() is defined in both codeigniter's URL helper and WordPress. I solved this using the following code:

```
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');

add_filter('site_url', 'ci_site_url', 1);

function ci_site_url() {
    include(BASEPATH.'application/config/config.php');
    return $config['base_url'];
}

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
```

Last line needs to be added as WordPress file was adding a HTTP response header 'HTTP/1.0 404 Page not found' to the header.

Now its fine to use WordPress functions to call in CodeIgntier.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to use WordPress templates in your codeigniter project. This works better for me so I wanted to share it. Tested with WordPress 3.3.1 and Codeigniter 2.1.

Directory Structure:

```
/ - WordPress
/ci/ - codeigniter
```

/ci/index.php (Top of CI Index file)

```
$wp_did_header = true;

if ( defined('E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR') )
    error_reporting(E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR |   E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR);
else
    error_reporting(E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING);

require_once("../wp-config.php");
```

Deal with the site_url function collision by overriding the default codeigniter version. You will need to change any place you used `site_url()` in codeigniter to use `ci_site_url()` instead.

/ci/application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php

```
<?php
function anchor($uri = '', $title = '', $attributes = '')
{
    $title = (string) $title;

    if ( ! is_array($uri))
    {
        $site_url = ( ! preg_match('!^\w+://! i', $uri)) ? ci_site_url($uri) : $uri;
    }
    else
    {
        $site_url = ci_site_url($uri);
    }

    if ($title == '')
    {
        $title = $site_url;
    }

    if ($attributes != '')
    {
        $attributes = _parse_attributes($attributes);
    }

    return '<a href="'.$site_url.'"'.$attributes.'>'.$title.'</a>';
}


if ( ! function_exists('ci_site_url'))
{
    function ci_site_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
    }
}

function current_url()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->ci_site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
}


function anchor_popup($uri = '', $title = '', $attributes = FALSE)
{
    $title = (string) $title;

    $site_url = ( ! preg_match('!^\w+://! i', $uri)) ? ci_site_url($uri) : $uri;

    if ($title == '')
    {
        $title = $site_url;
    }

    if ($attributes === FALSE)
    {
        return "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"window.open('".$site_url."', '_blank');\">".$title."</a>";
    }

    if ( ! is_array($attributes))
    {
        $attributes = array();
    }

    foreach (array('width' => '800', 'height' => '600', 'scrollbars' => 'yes', 'status' => 'yes', 'resizable' => 'yes', 'screenx' => '0', 'screeny' => '0', ) as $key => $val)
    {
        $atts[$key] = ( ! isset($attributes[$key])) ? $val : $attributes[$key];
        unset($attributes[$key]);
    }

    if ($attributes != '')
    {
        $attributes = _parse_attributes($attributes);
    }

    return "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"window.open('".$site_url."', '_blank', '"._parse_attributes($atts, TRUE)."');\"$attributes>".$title."</a>";
}



function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('#^https?://#i', $uri))
    {
        $uri = ci_site_url($uri);
    }

    switch($method)
    {
        case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
            break;
        default         : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
```

You can now use the WordPress `get_header()` and/or `get_footer()` functions to draw the template in your CI project.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Wordpress for managing articles in a custom CI e-commerce website. CI is my main site. The directory structure is the following:

```
 /application (CI)
 /... (directories like javascript, stylesheets ...)
 /system (CI)
 /wordpress
 /.htaccess
 /index.php (CI)
```

I'm able to use Wordpress functions in my CI controllers without my URLs being messed up when adding the following code to the top of CI's **index.php**:

```
require_once './wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';

add_filter('site_url', 'ci_site_url', 1);

function ci_site_url($uri = '') {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $uri = ltrim(str_replace($CI->config->base_url('wordpress/'), '', $uri),'/'); // "wordpress/" is in my case the name of the directory where I installed Wordpress. See directory structure above.
    return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
}
```

Works also when using CI i18n library by Jérôme Jaglale (http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n).

Answer (score 0):

if you're planning on using the code ignitor site_url function in your code, or if you're doing a merge of an existing CI site and WP... this might be helpful:

at the top of CI index.php:

```
require_once '../wp-blog-header.php';

add_filter('site_url', 'ci_site_url', 4);

function ci_site_url($url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $new_path = str_replace("YOURSITEURLGOESHERE", "", $url);
    return  $CI->config->site_url($new_path);
}
```

effectively this allows you to use site_url in CI, so if you've already added a ton of links and content to your project it might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 6.1 Version and Codeigniter - 4

```
 /* Folder structure like
   Public_html/ WordPress
   Public_html/Codeigniter /*



 //Call WordPress wp_load file inside CodeIgniter in this way 
   // Add this code into Public_html/Codeigniter/Public/index.php

 $mypath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php';
 include_once($mypath);



 // Call header and Footer in to view page 
  // Add this code into Public_html/Codeigniter/App/Views/welcome_message.php
   
<?php get_header(); ?>
 
<body>
    <h3>
It works!</h3>
 
</body>
</html>
 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```