# How can I host multiple sites on WAMP and CodeIgniter?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I am currently developing a CoeIgniter website on WAMP (in offline mode). However, I would like to develop two more:

- One CI site
- And one Wordpress site

For the CI site, I've read that you can have multiple application folders (all pointing to the same system folder), but I'm not sure how to direct the request to one or the other. And I don't know anything about how I could go about hosting word-press and CI on the same server. Is it possible to do this?

**EDIT:** this is not online, it is on my home Windows computer

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your responses everybody, I figured it out, it involved creating virtual hosts in my apache build.

I did it using this very good tutorial: http://cesaric.com/?p=255

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your host. But most hosts will let you put your apps in different directories and point each domain name to a specific app. In most cases you have some kind of domain manager that lets you assign each domain to a subdirectory of the webroot. If it's not obvious, just look at your host's support.

I don't know if you saw this, but this is how you would run multiple CodeIgniter apps using the same system:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html

Answer (score 1):

[How to integrate WordPress template with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253906/how-to-integrate-wordpress-template-with-codeigniter)

That will help you with WP

Answer (score 1):

You can just put them in different folders in the "wamp/www" directory

```
c:\wamp\www\codeigniter
c:\wamp\www\wordpress
```

Then you can create a MySQL database for each project.

To view these folders in a browser, you'd simply go to http://localhost/codeigniter and http://localhost/wordpress respectively.