# Wordpress query in CodeIgniter model

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I have the following method in a CI model:

```
function getPostTitle($post_slug)
{
 global $post;
 $posts = new WP_Query('name=' . $post_slug);

 while ( $posts->have_posts() ) 
    { 
   $posts->the_post();
   return $post->post_name;
 }
}
```

The returned variable is empty. Note that the **same code works fine in a view**. I need to be able to use the above query in a model so that is available to the controller. Any Wordpress/Codeigniter experts?

Comment: "The same code works fine in a view".  You mean a CI view?  If so, how are you tying CI and WordPress together so that WordPress methods are available to CI and visa versa?

Comment: Yes, I meant a CI view. The methods of Wordpress are available (globally) inside any CI view. You just place the CI system folder in the same directory as the Wordpress installation. Also, follow the guidelines here: http://philpalmieri.com/2009/06/codeigniter-and-wordpress-play-well-together/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this quote from the philplmieri.com link you supplied is a key to the answer:

"all the functions are available to you in your templates and views in ci.."

Maybe all WordPress functions aren't available in controllers and models, only views.

Another avenue is to test whether [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) works in the model instead of WP_Query().

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed that. No query function works in controllers/models, although other functions seem to work, for example: get_the_category(), get_tags().

Comment: I found two links on the topic of integragrating CI and WP:http://jidd.jimisaacs.com/archives/892/    and    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253906/how-to-integrate-wordpress-template-with-codeigniter