# How Can I integrate Wordpress with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, integration

I'm trying to use WordPress functions with php, and i'm having some troubles..

the error message says:
Call to undefined method stdClass::set_prefix() in /hd2/www/WWW_BACKUP/www-lalala/blog/wp-settings.php on line 287

Comment: please search before you post a question , there are tons of wordpress&codeigniter results , here's one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253906/how-to-integrate-wordpress-template-with-codeigniter

Comment: why would you ever want to integrate wordpress with codeigniter. Wordpress is almost a full-fledged framework built for a specific purpose, and its extremely powerful if one reads the documentation and uses its built in functions.

Comment: I supposed he's has some very specific requirements, like add a codeignater layer to a wordpress installation... Before critize other, please try to help.

Comment: Shivaas, Wordpress is not a framework. Wordpress is a blogging engine that kind of evolved into a very basic content management system, it can't do everything and sometimes it's easier using a third party PHP framework like Codeigniter to accomplish things than to write a plugin for Wordpress that does the same thing. Don't get me started on the code-base of Wordpress, it's a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to **integrate** the two, as Wordpress is not a development framework.  I am making a *BIG* assumption that you really want to just have it in the same 'directory' and be able to utilize the same database?

I've seen that done before, and it involves simply sharing config files for your database (include wordpress config inside codeigniter, etc).

Just stick CI inside a folder inside your Wordpress directory:

```
/website/
  /ci/ (codeigniter runs inside here)
  /wp-content/
  /wp...
  ...
  index.php (wordpress)
  .htaccess (combined wordpress / ci functionality)
```

Then you would just *duck* inside the `/ci` folder for CI functionality and redirect back to Wordpress after.

---

As far as integrating with merge of CODE (ie, wordpress with CI running inside of it or vice versa) that is pointless and most would argue a waste of time.

Wordpress already offers most of the features you would want to build in CI (session tracking / database active querying / basic CRUD functionality / user management).

If all you seek is to utilize some small 'functions' in Wordpress that you get in CI, I would say focus on *porting* those alone.

Nothing good can come of you merging two applications together like this.