# How to use Codeigniter in existing wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have a existing WordPress site and I want to use Codeigniter in my existing wordpress site using a subfolder so please let me know the folder structure where should i create subfolder for codeigniter and what changes should done to run the subfolder.

Looking forward for quick response. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? I'd think that putting CodeIgniter in a subfolder and set it up as usual would suffice (but I might be wrong, hence the question.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/website/
  /ci/ (codeigniter runs inside here)
  /wp-content/
  /wp...
  ...
  index.php (wordpress)
  .htaccess (combined wordpress / ci functionality)
```

Make suru you configure the Codeigniter correctly. Take a look at [this guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html).

Also following questions

- [How Can I integrate Wordpress with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4608550/12731030)
- [How to integrate WordPress template with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1253906/12731030)