# Use wordpress 3.x.x functions in an external application

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, integration

I'm trying to accomplish a similar thing to what was asked in this question [How to integrate WordPress template with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253906/how-to-integrate-wordpress-template-with-codeigniter) but my code igniter application is running in a directory above wordpress's and under a subdomain.

I think its worth saying also that putting the code igniter application under the same domain as wordpress does not stop the redirect to the installer.

I tried the solutions on that page as well as a few others from Google'n about. None of them seem to work.

As soon as I include ANY wordpress file the code igniter file redirects to "domain.com/wp-admin/install.php"
I'm using the latest wordpress version 3.1.4 I believe it is. Has anyone done this or knows how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch that, its obviously the wrong approach to making the two systems work together but if you're in a situation like me where your code igniter website is long established and so is the wordpress set up then find another route. If you have wordpress setup and are about to start a code igniter app the consider how they'll integrate before getting into it. Perhaps write a wordpress plugin instead, if its the otherway around then consider writing your own blog application with codeigniter.

In my case I have no choice with two established systems. Wordpress provides an XML-RPC interface. I've decided it will be a lot less painful to use it. See http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support for more info on it. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extended-xml-rpc-api/

Might also be useful to someone:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-restful/