# Making blog By codeigniter 

Tags: codeigniter

I am currently working on a codeigniter project, now i want a option "Blog" where user can post and comment. A post can contain images , tables, different fonts, similar case is for comments . I am novice in webdevelopment, only know php and it's one framework. Would you please anyone suggest me,what should i do ?

NEW:

After this post i got some good advice and i took decision to use rich text editor tiny_mce but my bad luck that again i am having problem . I can't include the tiny_mce or after including it's not working . I worked how  they instructed but no change normal textarea is coming . What should i do?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <script  src="<?php echo base_url("js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"); ?>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
      <script  src="<?php echo base_url("js/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"); ?>" type="text/javascript" ></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    //  content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        formats : {
            alignleft : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'left'},
            aligncenter : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'center'},
            alignright : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'right'},
            alignfull : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'full'},
            bold : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'bold'},
            italic : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'italic'},
            underline : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'underline', exact : true},
            strikethrough : {inline : 'del'}
        },

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>

 </head>

 <body>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <div>
        <div>
        <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%"></textarea>
        </div>


        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />

      </div>
</form>

     </body>


</html>
```

Comment: If you want you can use PyroCMS, it is a CMS built on CodeIgniter so it's easy to customize with what you need and it already have  aBlog option. here more info: http://www.pyrocms.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [basic blog tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/) and also  [check this one](http://eeinsider.com/articles/building-with-codeigniter-adding-the-blog/) but you can use WordPress for blog with codeigniter and here is an answer on so about integrating [WordPress with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253906/how-to-integrate-wordpress-template-with-codeigniter).

[About WordPress.](http://wordpress.org/about/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also you could use the PCG at thephpcode.com to generate your Codeigniter blog module with images and rich text.

Comment: @Nish i am not understanding what you are saying . how could i use the pcg   and rich text editor ? would you please explain a little bit.

Comment: I mean you can generate Codeigniter website or blog at thephpcode.com, using PHP Code Generator (PCG). You can select field type rich text for the content field in the blog module so that it will allow rich text input in the generated website. Hope I explained well.

Comment: then what will be the datatype of post and comment ? If i ask like a stupid please forgive me. A simple blog having comment and post , have datatype "verchar" . Using rich text editor I get image tables texts formatted , but are they managed by verchar, how i put them in database ,normally like text or something special? @Nish

Comment: Choose mysql TEXT type, that is good for big text than varchar