# Codeigniter best way to handle templates

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am building a small cms in codeigniter and I love the way word press uses templates I in wp-contnet a separate folder to their cms code. I have seen a few examples on how to use parsing classes etc and also how to use word press with codeigniter.

Are their any template engines that work like word press ie uses a thumbnail to show the template in admin and parsing style.css for the name of template.

I have seen these two examples come close

[How to integrate WordPress template with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253906/how-to-integrate-wordpress-template-with-codeigniter)

and

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html

but it looks like that it is also has to be in the views path C