# Is it right to use Wordpress template with codeigniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have been using codeigniter and wordpress for quite a long time. But now I have a different kind of requirement. I need to use a wordpress template with codeigniter as my core.

I have some concerns on this :

1. Is it really possible ?
2. If it is possible , is this a right thing to do ?

I want some really good suggestions on this.

Additional details:
I am using **Codeigniter 2.2** and **Wordpress 4.3.1**

Comment: If it is a requirement to do this then your question of `is this a right thing to do?` is irrelevant. You sound like an expert in both technologies so do you have a plan for creating this merger?

Comment: i am planning it but i think it will create lots of problem in the terms of content.

Comment: You are most likely correct about causing lots of issues so you should read what others have done first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253906/how-to-integrate-wordpress-template-with-codeigniter https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-igniter/